# How to reverse all words in a ms-word document with C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

The document formatting should not change. Nothing change other than words order.

Document :

```
Word1 word2 word3 word2... -- END OF LINE OR PARAGRAPH
Word5 word1 word5 word4.....
```

After reversing should be like following

```
1droW 2drow 3drow 2drow... -- END OF LINE OR PARAGHRAPH
5droW 1drow 5drow 4drow.....
```

Already I have this code to go through words one by one but I don't have any idea how to change without missing formatting.

```
string RT = "";


Word.Application wordObject = new Word.Application();
wordObject.Visible = false;

Word.Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(@"D:\ELAHE (J)\a.docx");

String strLine;
bool bolEOF = false;

docs.Characters[1].Select();

int index = 0;
do {

    object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdWord;
    object count = 1;
    wordObject.Selection.MoveEnd(ref unit, ref count);

    wordObject.Selection.InsertBefore("‭");
    strLine = wordObject.Selection.Text;
    RT += ++index + " - " + strLine + "\r\n"; 


    object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    wordObject.Selection.Collapse(ref direction);

    if (cnt++ > 100) break;

    if (wordObject.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists(@"\EndOfDoc")) bolEOF = true;
} while (!bolEOF);

docs.Close();
wordObject.Quit();
docs = null;
wordObject = null;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this algorithm?

Comment: @PaulSasik I'm trying to reverse every single word in the document without missing it's style.

Comment: I understand that, but what will doing so accomplish for you in the end. I'm assuming that your algorithm as described is only part of a greater problem.

Comment: @PaulSasik The algorithm is not greater than this and my exact goal is to reverse words.

Comment: You could test via a regex pattern whether or not you have some valid alpha numeric value and when it finds a match to reverse it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just created a sample of how this can be done (C# 5.0, Word Interop v. 15 (Office 2013)). The code loops through each paragraph and reverses each word in a paragraph. The code includes a check for end-of-line symbols (`\r`) to make sure that these are not reversed.

I'm not 100% sure that `\r` is the only end-of-line symbol used by Word, so if you encounter other kinds, e.g. `\r\n` or something similar, it should be rather straight forward to include checks for these as well.

```
var wordApplication = new Application() { Visible = true };
var myDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\...\my.docx");

for (var i = 1; i <= myDocument.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    var paragraph = myDocument.Paragraphs[i];
    var words = paragraph.Range.Words.Cast<Range>().Select(r => r.Text).ToList();

    // Empty paragraph -> continue
    if(words.Count == 1 && words[0] == "\r")
        continue;

    for (var j = 0; j < words.Count; j++)
    {
        var word = words[j];

        // Should not be reversed
        if(word == "\r")
            continue;

        var reversed = new string(word.Trim().Reverse().ToArray());

        words[j] = (word.EndsWith(" ")) ? reversed + " " : reversed;
    }

    paragraph.Range.Text = string.Join("", words);
}
```